# Change temporary field on UI at button click in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

First take a look to the code :-

**my_model.py**

```
my_status = fields.Selection(
    selection=[
        ('1', _('Bad')),
        ('2', _('Normal')),
        ('3', _('Good'))
    ], store = False)
my_msg = fields.Text(_('Status message'), store = False ) 

...
...
...

@api.multi
def my_fn(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    ...
    # on_condition = some expression 
    ...
    if on_condition:  
        self.my_status = '1'
    else:
        self.my_status = '2'
        self.my_msg = 'Working'
```

**xml_file.xml**

```
...
...
<button colspan="2" type="object" string="Check" name="my_fn"/>
<field name="my_status"/>
<field name="my_msg"/>

...
...
```

Now when I am clicking on **Check** button it is calling my_fn() but mentioned write statement is not working . It should be reflected on UI after that function call . Its an requirement that **my_status** and **my_msg**  field should be of temporary storage type .

Another thing is that I want to execute that function in normal form view not in editable view so I can not use onchange method also .

Comment: Why you don't use Onchange methode instead your own function

Comment: How can we use onchange method on non stored field . One more thing is that that function will execute only when we will do any change for that field. But I want to trigger function in normal form view not by going to edit view of the form .